# Why do I get a 502 Bad Gateway Error When I Change My Routes File?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, routes

Whenever I add a line to my routes.rb file in Rails, the entire site comes back with a 502 Bad Gateway error. This is the line I'm adding:

```
map.connect '/experience-and-share/featured-articles/authors/:author', :controller => content, :action => 'featured_articles_authors_redirect'
```

The backtrace isn't telling me anything.

Comment: The only odd thing I notice about this route is that `content` is a variable instead of a string or symbol, which I could imagine would produce some sort of error, but probably not that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a syntax error because I forgot the quotes on the controller.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, to prevent the question from being shown as unanswered.